# User consent for Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

Using React Native and setting collection disabled by default in the firebase.json app:

```json
{
  "react-native": {
    "analytics_auto_collection_enabled": false,
    "crashlytics_auto_collection_enabled": false
  }
}
```

After user give consent to analytics collection I store his choice in preferences and since this happens in native code I run :

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(choice)
```

Then, should I retrieve user choice from storage and run again `setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled`on each startup or should I run this only when the preference changes again ? In other words, does FirebaseAnalytics remember last status of analyticsCollectionEnabled or does it read the default disabled value from the manifest on each startup ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may wonder about this after running some tests I can confirm that the preference is stored internally by both Firebase Analytics and Crashlytics. Therefore there is no need in running a new initialization upon every start up of the app.